MongoDB Transaction using mongo driver
bool
create_and_insert_doc (mongoc_client_session_t *session,
                       void *ctx,
                       bson_t **reply, /* out param for our server reply */
                       bson_error_t *error)
{
   /*
    * mongoc_collection_insert_one requires an uninitialized, stack-allocated
    * bson_t to receive the update result
    */
   bson_t local_reply;
   bson_t *doc = NULL;
   ctx_t *data = NULL;
   bool retval;


   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      doc = BCON_NEW ("new", BCON_INT32 (2), "val", BCON_INT32 (2));
      printf ("Running the user-defined callback in a newly created transaction...\n");
      data = (ctx_t *) ctx;
      retval = mongoc_collection_insert_one (data->collection, doc, data->insert_opts, &local_reply, error);
      {
         sleep(0.5);
      }  
   }
   printf ("sleep end...\n");
   /*
    * To return to the mongoc_client_session_with_transaction() method, set
    * *reply to a new copy of our local_reply before destroying it.
    */
   *reply = bson_copy (&local_reply);
   bson_destroy (&local_reply);

   bson_destroy (doc);
   return retval;
}

mongoc_client_session_with_transaction (session, &create_and_insert_doc, NULL, &ctx, &reply, &error);

When I make Transaction using mongoc driver above and run the code, it runs about 5 seconds just inserting documents.
Other operations like insert, update, create index are not blocked. Why is that?
I know mongodb use intention lock, Shared lock, exclusive lock. So If I make transaction which just inserts single documents, an intent exclusive lock is obtained for database and collection and an exclusive lock for the document.
I think I am missing or misunderstanding something. Thanks for reading.
I ran test code, checked db.currentOp(), ran insert, update, create index while running transaction.

What operation did you expect to be blocked?

I Thought operation like
deleting, updating, creating new index would be blocked during the transaction.
Because trying to delete, update or create index of  the same document needs EX lock for the document.
Sorry I got so late. By the way.

It should only block writes only for documents that have been used in the transaction, not all documents.

The following post tries to answer by viewing this case from the following four distinct points. As time avails, shall try to update the post by including codes demonstrating each point.

Reads inside a Transaction
Writes Inside a Transaction
Reads outside a Transaction
Writes outside a Transaction

Reads inside a Transaction
A Read operation inside a transaction gets documents as a snapshot at the time of the read operation. Since a transaction does not lock the documents it has read, these documents may be changed by other write operations outside. If such write operations happen prior to the completion of a transaction, then it has become a scenario that the transaction has been carried out based on stale documents.
If an application under a context cannot suffer from stale documents, then the Read operation must place a lock on the documents it has read. MongoDB advocates to use findOneAndUpdate operation under such circumstances. Please note that each collection being read needs to have a user defined key to accomplish this operation. As we can understand, this is an indirect way of locking a document. The following code is doing the same. For more, please refer to link 1 below.
employeeDoc = employeesCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: 1, status: "Active" },
   { $set: { lockId: ObjectId() } },
   { returnNewDocument: true }
)

Writes Inside a Transaction
A Write operation inside a transaction will always be safe from race condition since it locks the respective documents.
Reads outside a Transaction
A Read outside of a transaction will be ignorant of the Writes inside the transaction. However, these Reads cannot be called stale since the transaction has not been done.
Writes outside a Transaction
A Write outside of a transaction will need to wait if there is an ongoing transaction which has already placed locks on the same documents.
Citations:

In-progress Transactions and Stale Reads
Is this transaction safe from race conditions?
What are ACID Properties in Database Management Systems?

